# How to read specific columns from each URL and reiterate it for multiple urls

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, python-requests

I have multiple URLs in Column A as shown in the picture.

URL information:

. All the URLs doesn't have the same schema.

. All the URLs have the first sheet name as "Sheet1".

How can I read only 4 specific columns information from each URL and append the data to one data frame in python?

[image]

I have tried the below code: But able to read-only cell value, not the URL.

```
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('fdfaffff.json',scope)
#service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

ws = client.open_by_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sPYbuEmbY8EHHMhr5wQy3Eti_cYqNI6b3359NAuuWyE/edit#gid=0")

name = ws.worksheet("Sheet1")

import gspread
import gspread_dataframe as gd
df = gd.get_as_dataframe(name,evaluate_formulas = True,skiprows = 0, has_header = True)
df1 = df[['Links']]
df1
for i in df1.index:    #loop using df.index
    print(df1.iloc[i])
```

Getting output like this

Ignore the URL links if it is not same. I have given sample URLs here.

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about the result you expect and your current issue. Can you explain about `read only 4 specific columns information from each URL`? And also can you explain about your current issue?

Comment: Sorry If my post is confusing. Each google sheet URL has common sheet1 and in that 30 columns and 2000 rows are there. Now my current issue is instead of reading all 30 columns from each url I just want to read only 4 columns from each sheet1.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still clearly see the vision of your goal from your replying. So I cannot think of the solution and workarounds now. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.